# Using sed to search large number of files for specific string and replace it

Tags: bash, sed

What I am trying to do is search a large number of source files for a particular pattern and put in fort of this pattern another expression. The files I am looking in are all with the same extension *.F90.
My first step is to use grep and find all lines of those files containing allocate but not allocated, so I have:

```
grep –I “ allocate *(” *.F90 | grep –v allocated
```

The first problem that I have is that the bracket might be preceded by one or more spaces. I can have

```
 allocate( 
 or allocate ( 
 or allocate  (
```

This is why I need the “*” in the grep command.
The general rule however (besides the spaces) says that the allocate is followed by “(” and than comes the thing that is being allocated. So I have:

```
allocate ( array_name ( ....
```

again the spaces are optional 
So what I would like to do is find this string, and put in front of it the following:

```
If( allocated(array_name) ) deallocate(array_name)
```

and imidiately after this on the next line I would like to have the original string `allocate(array( … .`

Please note that the array_name is an alphanumeric string which after the substitutions is appearing in more than one place. It is the name of the array being alocated. 
I would be very grateful if someone can give me a hint how to do this. I am stuck and have no idea how to do it.

Comment: This is a bit tricky in a general case - e.g. if there are cases where `allocate(...)` is in an expression (like `something = allocate(...)` or if `array_name` is an expression (like `allocate(get_buffer())`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to replace `allocate ( array_name )` with `If( allocated(array_name) ) deallocate(array_name) allocate ( array_name )`.

In GNU or BSD sed you can do the following:

```
sed -i.bk -e '/allocated/t' \
  -e 's/allocate *( *\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\) *)/If( allocated(\1) ) deallocate(\1) &/' \
  *.F90
```

This will search and replace matching lines in *.F90 and skip lines with `allocated` on. The original file will be called *.F90.bk.

As @Anders Johansson mentioned there can be other cases where the argument to allocate is something not alphanum-underscore, then you can search for this before you search and replace:

```
for i in *.F90; do
    echo "$i"
    sed -n '/.*allocate *( *\([^ )]*\) *).*/{h; s//\1/; /^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/t
        x; p;}' "$i"
done
```

(note the newline after `t`, BSD sed interpret everything after t as a label). Press ctrl+v ctrl+j in bash to input a newline on the command line.

- `/a\(b\)c/` find line with matching string
- `h` *h*old the match `abc` into hold space
- `s//\1/` *s*ubstitute last match `abc` with first group `b`
- /^[a-z]*$/t if `b` matches `^[a-z]*$`, then branch to end of script
- `x` e*x*change hold space `abc` an pattern space `b`
- `p` *p*rint pattern space `b`

Answer (score 1):

```
cat old_file.txt | sed 's/allocate *( *\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)/If( allocated(\1) ) deallocate(\1)\
allocate(\1/' > new_file.txt
```